# Unable to compile xps after installing ROOT, missing libraries

Tags: c++, r, gcc, g++, bioconductor

I'm trying to install xps in R, and have installed [ROOT](https://root.cern.ch/) from CERN.

during compile I get:

```
TMLMath.cxx:51:19: fatal error: TMath.h: No such file or directory

 #include "TMath.h"
                   ^
compilation terminated.
make: *** [TMLMath.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘xps’
```

I tried adding this file manually, then another was required, then another, ... until the error was not just missing files but things being redefined (see [notes here](https://github.com/lmmx/devnotes/wiki/Installing-CERN's-ROOT-framework)), and again compile failed.

My ROOT details are:

```
Version   5.34/14  16 December 2013
ROOT 5.34/14 (heads/v5-34-00-patches@v5-34-13-131-gd110ad3, Jan 07 2014, 00:12:00 on linuxx8664gcc)

CINT/ROOT C/C++ Interpreter version 5.18.00, July 2, 2010
```

```
whereis root
root: /usr/bin/root /usr/bin/root.exe /etc/root /usr/bin/X11/root /usr/bin/X11/root.exe /usr/include/root /usr/share/root /usr/share/man/man1/root.1.gz
```

I tried to `make uninstall` on a freshly downloaded version of `root` and perhaps worryingly it did nothing (I deleted the folder I originally `make`'d from)

I'm guessing perhaps the version of ROOT I have is missing some of these because `xps` relies on an older version of ROOT? The manual shows  a very recent date however, so it's not like this is neglected software (if I understand correctly)...

ROOT installed fine, and [all prerequisites I could find](https://github.com/lmmx/devnotes/wiki/Installing-CERN's-ROOT-framework) were installed:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential dpkg-dev make g++ gcc binutils libx11-dev libxpm-dev libxft-dev libxext-dev gfortran libssl-dev libpcre3-dev libglu1-mesa-dev libglew-dev libftgl-dev libmysqlclient-dev libfftw3-dev libcfitsio3-dev graphviz-dev libavahi-compat-libdnssd-dev libldap2-dev python-dev libxml2-dev libkrb5-dev libgsl0-dev libqt4-dev xfs xfstt t1-xfree86-nonfree ttf-xfree86-nonfree ttf-xfree86-nonfree-syriac xfonts-75dpi xfonts-100dpi
```

Any help would be appreciated, please let me know if I ought provide more details of my system.

Full output from Bioconductor installation:

```
> biocLite('xps')
BioC_mirror: http://bioconductor.org
Using Bioconductor version 3.0 (BiocInstaller 1.16.1), R version 3.1.2.
Installing package(s) 'xps'
trying URL 'http://bioconductor.org/packages/3.0/bioc/src/contrib/xps_1.26.0.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 6669399 bytes (6.4 Mb)
opened URL
==================================================
downloaded 6.4 Mb

* installing *source* package ‘xps’ ...
checking for gcc... gcc -std=gnu99
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc -std=gnu99 accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc -std=gnu99 option to accept ANSI C... none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -std=gnu99 -E
checking for gcc... (cached) gcc -std=gnu99
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... (cached) yes
checking whether gcc -std=gnu99 accepts -g... (cached) yes
checking for gcc -std=gnu99 option to accept ANSI C... (cached) none needed
found ROOT version 5.34/14 in directory /usr
** libs
** arch - 
g++ -I/usr//include -O2 -Wall -fPIC -pthread -m64 -I/usr/include/root -c TMLMath.cxx
TMLMath.cxx:51:19: fatal error: TMath.h: No such file or directory
 #include "TMath.h"
                   ^
compilation terminated.
make: *** [TMLMath.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘xps’
* removing ‘/home/louis/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.1/xps’

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpZVOlbW/downloaded_packages’
Warning message:
In install.packages(pkgs = pkgs, lib = lib, repos = repos, ...) :
  installation of package ‘xps’ had non-zero exit status
```

**Edit:** I followed ROOTSYS variable changes before running R:

```
export ROOTSYS=/usr/
export "PATH=$ROOTSYS/bin:$PATH"
```

I initially had been using `ROOTSYS=/usr/include/root`, which is where I find the program with `whereis root`. This gives a different error however - `/usr/bin/root/include not a directory`. Hence using `ROOTSYS=/usr` ...

```
> source("http://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
Bioconductor version 3.0 (BiocInstaller 1.16.1), ?biocLite for help
> biocLite('xps')
BioC_mirror: http://bioconductor.org
Using Bioconductor version 3.0 (BiocInstaller 1.16.1), R version 3.1.2.
Installing package(s) 'xps'
trying URL 'http://bioconductor.org/packages/3.0/bioc/src/contrib/xps_1.26.0.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 6669399 bytes (6.4 Mb)
opened URL
==================================================
downloaded 6.4 Mb

* installing *source* package ‘xps’ ...
checking for gcc... gcc -std=gnu99
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc -std=gnu99 accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc -std=gnu99 option to accept ANSI C... none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -std=gnu99 -E
checking for gcc... (cached) gcc -std=gnu99
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... (cached) yes
checking whether gcc -std=gnu99 accepts -g... (cached) yes
checking for gcc -std=gnu99 option to accept ANSI C... (cached) none needed
found ROOT version 5.34/14 in directory /usr
** libs
** arch - 
g++ -I/usr/bin/root/include -O2 -Wall -fPIC -pthread -m64 -I/usr/include/root -c TMLMath.cxx
cc1plus: error: /usr/bin/root/include: Not a directory
make: *** [TMLMath.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘xps’
* removing ‘/home/louis/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.1/xps’

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/Rtmpc9EO9W/downloaded_packages’
Warning messages:
1: In install.packages(pkgs = pkgs, lib = lib, repos = repos, ...) :
  installation of package ‘xps’ had non-zero exit status
2: installed directory not writable, cannot update packages 'maptools'
```

Comment: Did you follow [these instructions](http://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/readmes/xps/README), particularly the shell variable `ROOTSYS`?

Comment: Ah, well yes, they didn't work oddly, please see the edit I just made - it doesn't find the directory at all in that case, hence I just set `ROOTSYS` to `/usr/` ... I don't think I set these before installing ROOT itself (which does seem to work)

Comment: The error message is `/usr/bin/root/include: Not a directory` meaning the compiler is trying to enter this directory, which doesn't exist. For example, what is the output of `locate TMLMath.h` or similar command?

Comment: `locate TMLMath.h` returns nothing, `locate TMath.h` gives my Downloads folder... `~/Downloads/root-6.02.04/include/TMath.h`
`~/Downloads/root-6.02.04/math/mathcore/inc/TMath.h`

Comment: ROOT doesn't look correctly installed then.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments above, ROOT was not correctly installed - I just got contacted by someone with the same problem thinking it was unsolved (I'd left notes on the solution [here](https://github.com/lmmx/devnotes/wiki/Installing-CERN's-ROOT-framework) rather than on this question). I know S.O. policy is to include the fix rather than link out, so I'm pasting it below the following section divider. At a guess I'd say the advice given to use v5.34.24 rather than production should still apply (perhaps it will be specified somewhere, or else someone can contact the maintainer again). [I've taken out a section on a manual fix that didn't work]

---

### Prerequisites

(Via [Elena Graverini's blog](http://www.graverini.net/elena/computing/physics-software/install-root/))

Prerequisites:

`sudo apt-get install build-essential git subversion dpkg-dev make g++ gcc binutils libx11-dev libxpm-dev libxft-dev libxext-dev`

Optional (recommended) prerequisites:

`sudo apt-get install gfortran libssl-dev libpcre3-dev libglu1-mesa-dev libglew-dev libftgl-dev libmysqlclient-dev libfftw3-dev libcfitsio3-dev graphviz-dev libavahi-compat-libdnssd-dev libldap2-dev python-dev libxml2-dev libkrb5-dev libgsl0-dev libqt4-dev`

Install font server and fonts for ROOT:

```
sudo apt-get install xfs xfstt
sudo apt-get install t1-xfree86-nonfree ttf-xfree86-nonfree ttf-xfree86-nonfree-syriac xfonts-75dpi xfonts-100dpi
```

### Installation

- <strike>Find the pro (production) version number on [root.cern.ch](https://root.cern.ch/drupal/content/downloading-root)</strike>

  - The developer of `xps` recommends 5.34.24 as of February 4th 2015
- Get the `source.tar.gz` file at ftp://root.cern.ch/root/root_v5.34.24.source.tar.gz
- Do not install in `/usr/` directory (`xps` developer advice via email) as a lot of available guides suggest

```
gzip -dc root_v5.34.24.source.tar.gz | tar -xf -
mv root ~
cd ~/root
./configure --all
make -j N
```

where N is the number of CPU cores on your machine (`cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep 'cpu cores'`)

- For Ubuntu 14.04 run:
  `sudo mkdir /usr/include/freetype && sudo cp /usr/include/freetype2/freetype.h /usr/include/freetype/freetype.h`

  - **If you're uninstalling don't forget to take this out too**

#### Removing Ubuntu's version of ROOT resolves `ld` errors in `make`

`sudo apt-get purge root-system root-system-bin root-system-common`
`export ROOTSYS=/home/louis/root`

Rerunning make with config as `./configure --prefix=/home/louis/` works

- I think the prefix flag is equivalent to setting the `ROOTSYS` variable before `make` (I was using multiple guides and forgot to set it, but it worked regardless)
- The [CERN ROOT installation from source page](https://root.cern.ch/drupal/content/installing-root-source) notes that `make install` is a "[NOOP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NOP)"... but it isn't installed unless you run this after `make`, so do it anyway

Last step is to add $ROOTSYS/bin to PATH - add `source ~/bin/thisroot.sh` to your `~/.bashrc` (assuming your .bashrc is already sourced in new terminals)

- For me, `ROOTSYS` is now set in shells. [The xps README](http://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/readmes/xps/README) suggests you set it, but PATH isn't, so I proceeded to add the following to my .bashrc:

```
export PATH=$ROOTSYS/bin:$PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$ROOTSYS/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

`ROOT` should now be operational, and able to compile `xps`...

- For some reason LD_LIBRARY_PATH doesn't get set but PATH does...? .bashrc is otherwise all working as expected

```
cd $ROOTSYS/tutorials`
root
root [0] .x demos.C
```

If no errors appear, ROOT is working.

### Installing `xps`

I'd expect biocLite('xps') to fail as the binary was created with ROOT v.5.34.05... but the v5.34.24 was recommended by the maintainer so attempt it anyway:

```
source("http://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
biocLite("xps")
```

and it works :-)

- It's also possible to download from source and bypass Bioconductor by running `R CMD INSTALL xps_1.26.0.tar.gz`
- *RootTalk* Discussion Forums (including a [ROOT Support](https://root.cern.ch/phpBB3/viewforum.php?f=3&sid=ee0ac21adce1abf0a7af81ca81f1fd28) forum): https://root.cern.ch/phpBB3/